# HTML5 Validation - Override document.getElementById('inputID').validity.valid value

Tags: html, validation

I'm trying to perform both client-side & server-side e-mail validation.

I need a client validation on e-mail:

```
<input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-Mail" required>
```

There is also perform validation on server side if e-mail is exists, and if it does - I need that validation would fail (`invalid`).

How can I achieve this kind of functionality ? Is there a way to modify `document.getElementById('inputID').validity.valid` property to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API's_element.setCustomValidity()) method. If `error` param is not empty it will prevent form submitting and show your custom message:

```js
document.getElementById('inputID').setCustomValidity('Email already exists!');
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="inputID" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

As you can see in my snippet it will always show message, even if field is not empty and e-mail is valid. Also it prevent form submission.

To pass form submission you just need to call this method with empty string as param:

```
 document.getElementById('inputID').setCustomValidity('');
```

**Edit**

If you want it to check on blur you need to call [`checkValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) method:

```
document.getElementById('inputID').onblur = function( e ) {
  e.target.checkValidity();
};
```

Comment: setCustomValidity works only when hitting "submit".
I need a message exactly when blur event is fired.

Comment: but checkValidity doesn't refers to the data i found on server.

Here is my js code:
if(userExists)
{
  // Here I need set required to "invalid" value
}